# injective linear transformation basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T : V → W $ be an injective linear transformation, where
$V, W$ are vector spaces of dimension $n$ over the field $K$. If $\{e_1,\ldots , e_n\}$ is a
basis for $V$ , show that $\{T(e_1),\ldots , T(e_n)\}$ is a basis for $W$.

Comment: Hint: finite dimension+injective=bijective

Comment: I know if V = Span(v1, . . . , vr), then (v1, . . . , vr) is a basis for V if
v1, . . . , vr are linearly independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it will suffice to show that the vectors $T(e_i)$ are linearly independent. The rest will follow because of dimension reasons. Suppose that there are $a_1,\ldots,a_n \in K$ s.t.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i T(e_i)=0 $$

By linearity of $T$ you get

$$ T\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i\right)=0 $$

But now since $T$ is injective you get $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i=0$. But you know that the $e_i$ are linearly independent since they form a basis and therefore $a_i=0$ for all $i$. This shows that the $T(e_i)$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer.